# Cygwin Openssh can't see /etc/sshd_config

Tags: permissions, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I can't get the openssh server to work on Windows Server 2008. I have it working on two other servers, but one of them just won't work.

I run `ssh-host-config`, and choose privilege separation. Two users are created `sshd` and `sshd_server`.

Then I run `net start sshd`, and I see this:

```
The CYGWIN sshd service is starting.
The CYGWIN sshd service could not be started.

The service did not report an error.
```

Then I run `cat /var/log/sshd.log` and I see this output:

```
/etc/sshd_config: No such file or directory
```

I then check permissions on `/etc/sshd_config`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 sshd_server root 3344 Sep   7 09:15 /etc/sshd_config
```

So now, it seems sshd cannot see a file which is there and has the right permissions. Even on windows, that file is owned by `sshd_server`.

Comment: I have the same problem. It worked (on windows 8) for a few weeks but now after a restart it no longer works with the same problem as described here.

Answer (score 2):

had this happen too .
 a Procmon session revealed to me that the sshd service was trying to locate /etc in the root directory c:\etc instead of c:\cygwin\etc.

further investigation showed that sshd was loading an incorrect cygwin1.dll which was living in my system PATH environment variable.

solution was to either to remove the bad cygwin1.dll  or remove the "bad" path from the system variables and assigning that path it to user specific environment variables.

afterwards running the sshd daemon under a dedicated user who did not have this "bad "path worked as it should.

thanks mark